# Parsing xml file using xerces C++

Tags: c++, xml-parsing, xerces-c

I have an xml file to be parsed for the information contained to be further used. Can anyone help me with the xerces C++ code for parsing it? I have the xml creation code using xerces library as well in C++.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this doesn't help you much if you're already committed to xerces, but I'd recommend using [pugixml](http://pugixml.org/) instead. It's very easy to integrate, is very performant and has excellent documentation. I built a rather large project using it and had nothing but good experiences with it. It's of the nicest libraries I've ever used. (I'm not affiliated with them; just very happy).

Here is the documentation on parsing files: http://pugixml.googlecode.com/svn/tags/latest/docs/manual/access.html

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation. It would be very helpful if you could show me a code snippet as to how to write and parse xml files using pugixml.

Comment: The quickstart guide has that. http://pugixml.googlecode.com/svn/tags/latest/docs/quickstart.html#quickstart.main There are expanded examples in the full manual. http://pugixml.googlecode.com/svn/tags/latest/docs/manual/toc.html That source code is in the download of the source.